# How do I animate a UILabel in a cell?

Tags: swift, uitableview, animation, uilabel

I have a simple animation that fades a `UILabel` in and out. I have tested it on a label and it works, but I need it to work on a label inside a `UITableViewCell`, and it doesn't. The code looks like this:

```
extension UILabel {
    func animate() {
        UILabel.animate(withDuration: 2,
                       delay: 0.5,
                       options: [.repeat, .autoreverse, .curveEaseOut],
                       animations: { [weak self] in
                          self?.alpha = 0
        }, completion: { _ in
            self.alpha = 1
        })
    }
}
```

Also, I'm using `RxSwift`, if that matters. How do I make this happen? And why doesn't it work?

***EDIT***

I'm calling the extension from the `cell` class, when setting its `viewModel`:

```
class DownloadParameterTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {
    static let identifier: String = "DownloadParameterTableViewCell"
    private var disposeBag = DisposeBag()
    
    @IBOutlet weak var checkMarkImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nameLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var valueLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var currentValueLabel: UILabel!
    
    var viewModel: DownloadParameterTableViewCellViewModel? {
        didSet {
            disposeBag = DisposeBag()
            
            nameLabel.text = viewModel?.name
            valueLabel.text = viewModel?.parameterValueUnit
            currentValueLabel.text = viewModel?.currentParameterValueUnit
            
            if !(viewModel?.isValidParameter ?? true) {
                self.backgroundColor = .invalidParameterColor
                nameLabel.animate()
            }

            setBindings()
        }
    }...
```

Comment: Where and how are you telling it to animate? Where are you calling the `aninate()` function?

Comment: @Fogmeister I added a description above :)

Comment: Put it in `DispatchQueue.main.async { nameLabel.animate() } `, it may be helping

Comment: Nice, the dispatch worked! Thanks :)